# Data segragation in Firebase Realtime Database in React native via expo project

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

Im newbie to react native esp to android platform. And I have this problem about data segragation. Now, I can insert data to the database but it will create another every data I inserted with the same storename, thats my problem.  [image: It looks like this]

My expected output is:

- Runtest #1. The user#1 will create an order and choose the "Store#1", then it will create an node at db indicating user#1, order at STORE #1.
- Runtest #2.  User #2, create an order and choose "Store #5", so another node will create in database.
- Runtest #3. User #10, create an order and choose "Store#1" again, so in this case, there's no additional node after "Store#5". However it will just add into the node of Store #1.

This is my code in inserting data:

```
function create() {
  //  const newKey = push(child(ref(db), 'Orders')).key;
  const RandomId=Math.floor(Math.random()*500) +1;
  const newOrderRef = push(ref(db, 'Orders'));
 // const newOrderKey = newOrderRef.key;
 const newOrderKey = RandomId;
    set(ref(db,`Orders/${newOrderKey}`),{
      //orderID:RandomId,
    }).then(()=>{
      Alert.alert('Order','Order successfully.','OK');
    })
    .catch((error)=>{
      Alert.alert('Error',JSON.stringify(error),'OK');
    });
  }
```

Edit:  This is my exported JSON looks like.

```
   "Orders": {
   "100": {
   "orderUniqueID": 100,
    "TypeODelivery": "reservation",
    "amount": 100,
    "status": "Processing",
    "TypeOfOrder": "New Order",
    "Quantity": 5,
    "ReserveDate": "",
    "NameOfStore": "Store#1 ",
    
    "ProductPrice": 20,
    "ProductType": "Solid"
   }
 },
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Are you saying that you call `create` 3 times, but are not getting the expected results in the database? If so, can you edit your question to show exactly what JSON you get in the database (as text, no screenshots please)? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Sorry for confusion sir, I mean if the user will order the same store, the list of customer will store in that store and It wont create another STORE NODE.
That's why Im asking if how, or maybe there is a link/tutorial in how to manage the query in my Create function. 
And I already Edit my post sir, I included a JSON code.

Comment: Don't describe the problem in more words please. Instead show us the [exact code we need to run to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). So test if calling `create` three times causes the problem, and if so: show the code for that. In that case, you'll also want to `console.log(newOrderKey)` after you give it its value, to see if that is indeed unique each time.

Comment: And also I console the newOrderKey, and it gives me a unique ID. 

This is my codes sir here. 
https://codeshare.io/bvObWw

Comment: About what you've said sir, "as text, no screenshots please", Im sorry sir cause I cant explain well in text, so to make I sure that I delivered my concern, I make an visual representation of my expected output.

Again, I created another image, This is the link sir. https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIGxG.png